# Google map API in Homepage - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I need to use the google API in my homepage. 
what I have done is create a custom template and done all my work there, but now I need to show all the code on my homepage, and I don't know where to put that code. Because I am unable to find the homepage.php or anything like this.
Just give me an idea how to do this ?

Comment: have you searched for index.php? It may be also proper to ask at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page in backend home page and select as your frontpage.
   Apperenace -> Customize -> staticpage-> and your page name to make it home page
   and now put the code in that file .

Or 
2.follow these steps:
step 1-> Create a page-tamplate folder in wp-content folder
step 2-> Create a php file and add the below code at the top

```
<?php
```

/**
 * Template Name: Home page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

Your google api code or your home page code

Step 3-> now create a page from backend and aasign the page-tamplate Home page and published that your code will be visible on home page.

Comment: my site is http://daewoocab.com.pk/ and i want to show my foem and my map in book a cab section.